# Clone a Scene in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Is there a way to clone a scene in JavaFX ?

I currently want to keep a reference of the previous scene but can't find a simple way of doing it (except passing in the previous scene as a parameter to every new class responsible for scene creation).

Heres what I was thinking of doing (this is a snipped of my view controller)

```
public void switchScene(Scene newScene){

    previousScene = currentScene; // something which achieves this without aliasing

    currentScene = newScene;

    window.setScene(newScene);

}.
```

However as one can observe this leads to aliasing problems.

Any way to solve this problem ?

Comment: what worries you about this approach? in fact, everything comes down to it, the question is just what level to keep the copy.

Comment: If you need access to more scenes than one that were displayed before you could store the scenes in a `List`/`Map` or similar data structure. If this isn't the question I didn't get the question.

Comment: Yup..I am currently storing the Scenes in a Queue and this does allow me to go back to the previous Scene. But my question still remains - is there a way to clone a Scene in JavaFX ?